# Two fluid height divs inside a fixed height container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I almost didn't dare to ask this question because it looks trivial but after spending more than 3 hours on stackoverflow and Google, I had to give it a go.

My problem: http://jsfiddle.net/RVPkm/7/

On initial state, the `div#container` is going to contain `div#list-dynamic-2`, where I want `div#list-dynamic-2` to use the `div#container`'s full height. `Div#list-dynamic-1` is going to be inserted dynamically and is allowed to stretch up to `150px`. Once `div#list-dynamic-1`'s height reaches `150px`, I want `div#list-dynamic-2` to use the remaining space of `150px`.
I would also be happy if someone could tell me that this is pointless to achieve with CSS only and should be done with JavaScript instead.

(Btw, this is a simple example to show the problem and real usage would be to move selected users into the upper div and allow it to use 1/2 of `div#container`. Think of the upper `div` as some kind of shopping cart for users.)

Comment: @James Montagne Thanks! Highlighting makes it much more readable and I'll remember to use it next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a javascript solution:

```
var iDiff = 300 - document.getElementById('list-dynamic-1').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('list-dynamic-2').style.height = iDiff + 'px';
```

Then you can remove `max-height` and `height` from css definition for `#list-dynamic-2`.

Also see [your updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/RVPkm/9/).

For css I think you have to [calculate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/calc), but most browsers don't support it yet.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that there isn't a CSS only solution but hey, your solution is brilliant and works flawlessly in IE aswell. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of the [jQuery UI Layout Plug-in](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/).
See demo: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/nested_sidebars.html